# Interpret javascript code after loading AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, request

So i have an index.php page loading content in a div "container" with ajax
my problem is that i have a part of javascript inside one of my html include.
and it is not working when i make my ajax request, i get my content but not the js How can i fix it to interpret the javascript after loading ajax?
so this is the php request:

```html
<div id="container">
    <?php
    $d = "container/";
    if (isset($_GET['p'])) {
        $p = strtolower($_GET['p']);
        if (preg_match("/^[a-z0-9\-]+$/", $p) && file_exists($d . $p . ".html")) {
            include $d . $p . ".html";
        } else {
            include "pages/404.html";
        }
    } else {
        include "pages/index.html";
    }
    ?>
</div>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/ajax.js"></script>
```

In here my index.html page:

```html
<div class="section vs-section" data-speed="0.4">
    <div class="vs-transform" data-speed="0.5">
        <div class="overlay"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    var DOMReady = function (a, b, c) {
        b = document, c = 'addEventListener';
        b[c] ? b[c]('DOMContentLoaded', a) : window.attachEvent('onload', a)
    }
    DOMReady(function () {

        var section = document.querySelector('.vs-section');
        var divs = document.querySelectorAll('.vs-transform');

        var smooth = new Smooth({
            direction: 'horizontal',
            section: section,
            ease: 0.1,
            els: divs
        });
        smooth.init();
    });
</script>
```

And finally my ajax:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#menu a").click(function () {
        $("#top").append('<div class="loader"></div>'); // On ajoute le loader en haut
        page = $(this).attr("href");
        $.ajax({
            url: "pages/" + page,
            cache: false,
            success: function (html) {
                afficher(html);
            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                afficher("erreur lors du chagement de la page");
            }
        })
        return false;
    });
});

function afficher(data) {
    $(".loader").remove(); // On supprime le loader
    $("#container").fadeOut(500, function () {
        $("#container").empty();
        $("#container").append(data);
        $("#container").fadeIn(1000);
    })
}
```

Comment: I've had this problem myself several times. The trick I used to solve it was having the Javascript code on the main index.php file instead. Then put a custom event trigger on the div container everytime some page is loaded into it. Detect which page it is using a simple if statement and execute the Javascript code if it's (in your case) index.html. The difference is though that I used JS to load pages, not PHP. So I'm not entirely sure if the same solution will work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the similar type of code on my website. The trick is to put the javascript code that is being loaded inside `$(document).ready`. You can have multiple `$(document).ready` on same page so that wouldn't be a problem.

So firstly load the jquery before container div. And make sure the data that is being loaded dynamically has the javascript code inside `$(document).ready`.

Here have a look at my site I did them same http://brozeus.xyz/ Look at its source, it loads the content from http://brozeus.xyz/body.php inside the page dynamically and the javascript code inside http://brozeus.xyz/body.php also runs after data is apppended via `.append()` function. So have a look at source of http://brozeus.xyz/body.php too.

Comment: actually my problem is not the "ajax function" animation the fadein and fadeout work well the problem is the part of the js i have in my html include is not interpreted by ajax when i make my request...

Comment: @tib I have answered for that only. If you see the site and source you will notice that the index.php loads body.php content dynamically via ajax request and the JS inside body.php is in `$(docment).ready` function and it is interpreted.

Comment: my problem come from the js inside my html, because actually if i replace it by an alert, it is working well... but i don not know how to syntax it for make it work ....

Comment: @tib Ah so looking at the JS it seems as if it requires a plugin so have you included that plugin? And why are you making custom DOMReady function? Just use `$(document).ready` in place of DOMReady

Comment: Ah it is working if i put my jquery and my main.js in my html